# JQuery dialog - make background transparent but still moveable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, transparency

I'm trying to add a transparent JQuery dialog. But I'm running into two issues:

- The background on the text, "Hello", won't become transparent
- After removing the titlebar, I can no longer drag the dialog

The comments are what I tried so far.

```
    //Create new components
    var newComponent= "<div id='Component"+ componentOffset  +"' class='ui-widget'><h1>Hello</h1></div>";
    $('#rootArea').append(newComponent);
    $('#Component' + componentOffset).dialog({
        dialogClass: 'transparent-dialog'
    });
    //$('#Component' + componentOffset).css('background-color', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0)');
    //Adding style to newComponent div: style='background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0); '
```

css:

```
.transparent-dialog {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);    
}

.transparent-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
display:none
}
```

[image]

The goal is to make it only show borders and background upon hovering over. I figured I could also display the title bar again upon hovering. This way I can still drag the component without to much trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To cause all jQueryUI dialogs to be transparent, just override the default styles for the widget by adding the following to your custom CSS file (there should be no need to add your custom `.transparent-dialog` class as a result):

**CSS:**

```
.ui-widget-header {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.ui-widget-content {
  background: transparent;
}
```

If you want just one specific dialog to be transparent and others to retain the background, then you can target it with your id or give it an additional class, such as:

```
.transparent-dialog {
  background: transparent;
}
.transparent-dialog .ui-widget-header {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.transparent-dialog .ui-widget-content {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I have several dialogs. Only one or two should be transparent. So I can't use the default css elements.

Comment: See the second part of my answer.

Comment: First part works perfect. Second doesn't, but it's probably me doing something wrong.

Comment: Needed to set the ".transparent-dialog" class transparent as well. Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it.  Updated my answer to reflect what worked for you in hopes it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

jquery ui also has an option called [dialogClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-dialogClass)
This worked for me:

```
<style>
.yellow-dialog {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>

<div id="my-dialog">Hello</div>

<script>
$("#my-dialog").dialog({
  modal: true,
  dialogClass: "yellow-dialog"
});
</script>
```